# Firefox Date String

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I'm having trouble with firefox converting date object to `date string`.

Here is the piece of my JS code:

```
var dt = Date('2014-05-10');
alert(dt.toString());
```

My timezone on my PC is set to Eastern Time Zone.
This is what I am getting using different browsers:

```
Firefox:
Wed May 14 2014 10:13:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)

Chrome:
Wed May 14 2014 10:14:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

IE:
Wed May 14 10:15:14 EDT 2014
```

Any idea why I am getting EST on Firefox?

Comment: What format are you expecting? What do you want to do with this string?

Comment: Because Firefox doesn't distinguish DST, and only cares about the administrative timezone? It's got the correct time and offset.

Comment: I think remember firefox relay on 'TZ' system property to display the date. Check if this property is defined in your system.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158328

Comment: In my computer (Windows 7), Firefox doesn't even show the time zone, just the offset: `"Wed May 14 2014 16:28:14 GMT+0200"`. I guess it's simply a piece of data you can't rely on.